# Make a direct call to Kubernetes pod

Tags: http, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have several pods running inside the Kubernetes cluster.
How I can make http call to a specific Pod, without calling LoadBalancer service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`...make http call to a specific Pod, without calling LoadBalancer service?`

There are several ways, try `kubectl port-forward <pod name> 8080:80`, then open another terminal and you can now do `curl localhost:8080` which will forward your request to the pod. More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/).